# Using opencv to read a video file in Django, yet the cam won't open?

Tags: python, django, opencv, input

I am getting a video file from the user and storing it in the media folder. Then I pass a path to the file to a function, but when I use opencv to open the file, the cam won't open.

```
start = time.time()
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
fr = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

The video_name is of the form `/media/video_name.mp4`

The error report is the following

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (116)
cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:235: error: (-5:Bad 
argument) CAP_IMAGES: error, expected '0?[1-9][du]' pattern, got: /media/video_name.mp4 in function 
'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems like it's not the solution to the OP's problem, but since this error doesn't have a lot of hits when you google it, and it's the error message I was getting, I'll put this answer here in case it helps others.

I got this exact error in a C++ app when I built and ran in debug in Visual Studio using CMake but included both the opencv_world430 and opencv_world430d libs in the list of libs to link. Removing the non-debug opencv_world430 solved the problem.